# injecting nested inline script tag with angular.element() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to inject to my DOM the following nested string:

```
<div><script>alert(1);</script></div>
```

When I try using `angular.element()` for the task, it does add it to the DOM, but not triggering the inline script:

```
var body = angular.element(document.body);
var el = angular.element('<div><script>alert(1);</script></div>');
body.append(el);
```

If I use jQuery, it works great:

```
$('body').append('<div><script>alert(1);</script></div>');
```

When I explicitly create the DOM elements one by one, it also works:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.innerHTML='alert(1)';
d.appendChild(s);
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

So what's wrong with my angular solution?

Comment: angular strips any code appended like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution I found was to replace each script tag with a newly created one, and then attach to DOM.

http://jsbin.com/luxepicedo/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

For add script you can use this solution added by [endorama](https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006)

```
/*global angular */
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if (attr.type === 'text/javascript-lazy') {
          var code = elem.text();
          var f = new Function(code);
          f();
        }
      }
    };
  });

}(angular));
```

Just add this script in your template

```
<script type="text/javascript-lazy">
   alert(1);
</script>
```

Comment: It is triggered only when angular bootstraps - it goes over each script element. When I add new script code, it isn't triggered

Comment: FYI , angular is doing it via `.text` and not `.text()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370496/text-property-in-script-tags-clarification. upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
                    var body = angular.element(document.body);
                    var el = angular.element('<div><script>alert(1);</script></div>');
                    body.append(el);
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ang</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("demo",['ngRoute']);

        app.controller("firstCtrl",function($scope){
            $scope.submit = function(){
                var bod = angular.element(document.body);
                var el = "<div><script>alert(1)<\/script><\/div>";
                bod.append(el);
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        <button ng-click="submit()">TEST</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will not trigger inline script. Try $compile. Possibly will not work since you have already loaded the DOM. Put it in a function and trigger the function somewhere using some event handler or function call within Angularjs.