# Text property in script tags - Clarification?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While reading angular's directives code , I saw [**this**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/script.js#L43) :

```
var scriptDirective = ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      if (attr.type == 'text/ng-template') {
        var templateUrl = attr.id,
            text = element[0].text;// <-- Look here

        $templateCache.put(templateUrl, text);
      }
    }
  };
}];
```

But I didn't know what is that `text` property  ( I mean — why not use innerText ?)

I was told that :

*"it's like textContent just only grabs the text nodes inside the element, no recursion or the likes"*

Also looking at the [docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-script-text) :

> The IDL attribute text must return a concatenation of the contents of
>   all the Text nodes that are children of the script element (ignoring
>   any other nodes such as comments or elements), in tree order. On
>   setting, it must act the same way as the textContent IDL attribute.

Wasn't clear for me.

[Mdn's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-text) :

> **text**:Like the textContent attribute, this attribute sets the text content of the element.  Unlike the textContent attribute, however,
>   this attribute is evaluated as executable code after the node is
>   inserted into the DOM.

So I created a [**test**](http://jsbin.com/xateyatako/1/edit?html,console) :

```
<script id="a"   type="blabla">
 foo
   <b>bar</b>
   baz
</script> 


<script >
 console.log(document.getElementById('a').text)
 console.log(document.getElementById('a').textContent)
</script>
```

But both shows the *exact* content :

```
"
 foo
   <b>bar</b>
   baz
"
```

**Question:**

- Why does angular uses `text` and not  `textContent` ? if it's a template - then they do need to consider tags....no ?
- What is the difference (in *script* tags) between `innerText`/`text`/`textContent` ?

<sub>*BTW there is a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172305/difference-between-text-and-textcontent-properties) , but it doesn't talk much about the `script` scope (which is actually a must in my question)*</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fork of your jsbin where you can see the difference: http://jsbin.com/tovipiruce/1/edit?html,js,output

Or, if you're a snippets fan:

```js
var scriptElem = document.getElementById('a');

var child = document.createElement('b');
child.textContent = 'Look at me! I am irrelevant!';

var comment = document.createComment('I contain a lot of wisdom');
var justText = document.createTextNode('just your average text node');

scriptElem.appendChild(child);
scriptElem.appendChild(comment);
scriptElem.appendChild(justText);

console.log(scriptElem);
console.log('textContent:', scriptElem.textContent);
console.log('innerText:', scriptElem.innerText);
console.log('text:', scriptElem.text);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  
<p>Open your console</p>

<script id="a" type="blabla">
foo
<b>bar</b>
baz
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Big Difference here is how child elements are handled: `textContent` includes the child elements, so that the output **will** contain `Look at me! I am irrelevant!`, while `text` **will not**.

I'll repeat that in code:

```
scriptElem.textContent.includes('Look at me!'); // true
scriptElem.text.includes('Look at me!'); // false
```

#### The Getter

Let's look at a very naive implementing of the getters of `textContent` and `text`:

```
function textContent(elem) {
    return Array.from(elem.childNodes).map(node => {
        // recurse into element nodes
        if (node.type === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return textContent(elem);
        }

        // return the value of text nodes
        if (node.type === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            return node.nodeValue;
        }

        // and ignore everything else
        return '';
    }).join('');
}

function text(elem) {
    return Array.from(elem.childNodes).map(node => {
        // return the value of text nodes
        if (node.type === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            return node.nodeValue;
        }

        // and ignore everything else
        return '';
    }).join('');
}
```

As you can see (and as the specification says and the example shows), only text nodes are handled when `get`ting an element's `text` property, while `textContent` also throws into the mix the `textContent` of its element children.

`innerText` is a more complex beast which won't be explained in this answer; it's like a normalized `textContent`. You can read more about it [in this fabulous blog post by Kagnax](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/).

#### The Setter

Now let's talk about the `set`ter. The specification says it should behave the same way as setting `textContent`, but mdn says the following bizarre thing:

> Unlike the textContent attribute, however, this attribute is evaluated as executable code after the node is inserted into the DOM.

There're two ways to interpret this sentence: Either that setting a script's `textContent` before injecting it into the page has no effect while setting `text` does, or that after injecting it into the page setting `textContent` has no effect but setting `text` does.

Testing on latest Chrome (47) and Firefox (43) shows that both interpretations are false: setting a `textContent` before injection works, and setting `text` after injection has no effect. If someone has an IE lying around and wishes to test this, I'd appreciate if you edit this answer.

#### ...but why?

So we've gone through the setter and the getter. Now let's ask why is `text` useful? That's an open question. Frankly, I don't really know. As you've seen in your original code, you can't just insert markup in a script tag, it's not parsed as html. So the only way to see a difference is when you dynamically inject nodes inside a script tag.

I ran `git blame` on that file, and saw that it came from [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/94dd68570952f6f31abfa351b1159afcd3588a57):

> fix(script): Incorrectly reading script text on ie
>
> IE deals with script tags in special way and .text() does not work. Reading the .text property directly fixes the issue.

The added test case does a binding inside the script tag. I don't know angular so I don't know what that entails, nor do I have IE so I can't check what happens in the test case when you use `textContent` instead of `text`.

But I couldn't help but smile when I saw that IE was still alive and kickin'.

Comment: For those whom want to know the output result from IE, please check [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cw5pZ.jpg) which shows an output from FF (left) and IE (right). You can see that it acts the same way in that case.